# Новое название файла после импорта в php-excel laravel

Tags: laravel, phpexcel

Подскажите плиз, как при экспорте импортируемого файла получить новое имя?

```
Excel::load('files/monthly_report/monthly_report_template.xlsx', function($file) use ($request, $Month_r, $Month_d, $count, $money)  {    
        $file->first();
        $file->sheet('TS', function($sheet) use ($request, $Month_r, $Month_d, $count, $money) {
            $sheet->cell('B3', function($cell) use ($request, $Month_r){
                $cell->setValue('01 '.$Month_r[$request->month]);
            });
            $sheet->cell('D3', function($cell) use ($request){
                $cell->setValue($request->year);
            });
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
```

---

Такой вариант не срабатывает:

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($file) use ($request, $Month_r, $Month_d, $count, $money) { 
        Excel::load('files/monthly_report/monthly_report_template.xlsx', function($file) use ($request, $Month_r, $Month_d, $count, $money)  {    
            $file->first();
            $file->sheet('TS', function($sheet) use ($request, $Month_r, $Month_d, $count, $money) {
                $sheet->cell('B3', function($cell) use ($request, $Month_r){
                    $cell->setValue('01 '.$Month_r[$request->month]);
                });
                $sheet->cell('D3', function($cell) use ($request){
                    $cell->setValue($request->year);
                });
            });
});
        })->export('xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Название можно задавать через:
    `$excel = Excel::load($filePath);`
    `$excel->setFileName($name);`
Возможно сработает и так:
    `Excel::load($filePath)->setFileName($name)->export('xlsx');`